# Maps, nested maps and sink context

Tags: raku

This code returns nothing

```
<foo bar ber>.map: { $^a.comb.map: { $^b.say}};
```

It contains two [nested maps, both of them in sink context](https://docs.raku.org/language/traps#Beware_of_nesting_Maps_in_sink_context.). it shouldn't work, because [a list sunk in a sink context is a no-op](https://docs.raku.org/routine/sink#(List)_method_sink).

However, this works:

```
<foo bar ber>.map: *.say; # OUTPUT: «foo␤bar␤ber␤»
```

and it's again a list in sink context. So why does it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `map` does not return a `List`, but rather a `Seq`. A `Seq` is a one-shot `Iterable` sequence of values, and in sink context it will iterate its underlying iterator and discard the produced values. This is why a `map` in sink context will iterate, but only one level deep. Add `.flat` to sink even the inner values (by flattening them into a single top-level sequence):

```
<foo bar ber>.map({ $^a.comb.map: { $^b.say}}).flat # OUTPUT: «f␤o␤o␤b␤a␤r␤b␤e␤r␤»
```

A `List` would indeed not iterate its values in sink context, because a `List` is a data structure that memorizes even lazily produced values so that they can be indexed repeatedly. Indeed, doing:

```
(<foo bar ber>.map: *.say).list;
```

Produces no output, because the `Seq` was coerced into a `List`, which does nothing in sink context.

Very few built-in operations on iterable data return a `List`, since it would be a premature commitment to retain data. It's often useful to chain such operations together and have the data flow through them an item at a time, rather than having to be all held in memory at each intermediate step. This is what `Seq` enables, and why so many things return it instead of `List`.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is because only the *last* statement of a `map` is *not* sunk:

```
class A {
    method sink() {
        say "sunk"
    }
}
<foo bar ber>.map: { A.new }     # doesn't show 'sunk'
A.new;                           # shows 'sunk' once
<foo bar ber>.map: { A.new; 1 }  # shows 'sunk' 3x
```

So the inner `map` does not get sunk, and therefore doesn't run, because it's the `sink-all` on the inner map (that gets called on the iterator by the `sink` method) that makes things happen.

Comment: This is true, but doesn't address the real confusion in the question, which is that `map` does not return `List` at all.